# Indexing PDF from badly authored LaTeX source

Tags: pdf, latex

I've noticed this issue with some PDF files, that originate from LaTeX source (I assume that, from the page layout/design and fonts used).

So today I was reading such article and I couldn't copy meaningful text, nor do text search, and of course can't index the document. Here is one random example: http://www.vincent-net.com/luc/papers/00informatica_granul.pdf

Is there some procedure, I can make this kind of documents accessible. Only thing that comes to my mind is to rasterize document then do OCR as save it, but that feels just dumb.

Comment: The fonts used in that file neither use a standard character encoding nor have a usable /ToUnicode stream. While changing the former would mean heavy lifting, adding a /ToUnicode stream is feasible, you merely have to OCR the individual characters of each font and add a /ToUnicode mapping accordingly. That being said, I'm not aware of any tool available doing that out of the box, so I gather you'll have to implement that yourself...

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I just found similar report: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703387/pdf-font-encoding and after reading the answer and your comment, I conclude that easiest and fastest solution is to use GhostScript and output 600dpi tiff, then do OCR by tool of choice, and finally pack it in DjVu.

Comment: In fact I found even faster version, as I'm lately playing around with `djvudigital` - use `djvudigital` to output PDF to DjVu without text layer (or remove the layer `djvused sample.djvu -e 'remove-txt' -s`) and then do OCR on DjVu file by tool of choice. This is yet another great usage for DjVu enabled GhostScript, and result is just magical, in both quality and file size.

Comment: The drawback of the transformation of the whole document of course is that you lose interactive features of the PDF (forms, annotations, etc.). In case of PDFs only representing print documents that might be irrelevant, though.

Comment: Sure, my procedure if applicable where DjVu as format is, and as for some reason I notice this issue only on LaTeX sourced PDFs (could be coincidence, thou) then DjVu is reasonable choice as a solution. I wasn't sure if there is relatively easy way to fix such PDF files, fonts being included, but from your reply and linked answer, it's evident that PDF is too complex for playing around this problem.