# automatically extract text from pdf for many files

Tags: java, python, pdf, text

I have about 10,000 of pdf files(conf papers) and I need to extract text from certain section (like the experimental section) of these papers and save in a file.
Does anyone know a java tool or some python tool which can help me do this?

Thanks in advance

Ayush

Comment: I am not sure about just getting special part of pdf but for whole part you check my post to this question which much simpler than other methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583535/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-in-python/15588435#15588435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For java: have a look at iText

For python I would use PDFMiner

Comment: do you know the function in pdfbox which allows me to extract text only from certain section of the research articles rather then the whole text?

Answer (score 2):

Did you research your question before posting? I just googled and found this Apache project: http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: do you have any other suggestion like in python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665/python-module-for-converting-pdf-to-text suggests http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html

Comment: doe pdf box has a function to extract text only from a section of paper and not the entire text of the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Since these are academic papers, you should also really look at [lapdftext](https://github.com/BMKEG/lapdftext)

> LA-PDFText is a system for extracting accurate text from PDF-based
>   research articles (and an interface to be able to improve performance
>   where needed). The system is open-source and provides a simple
>   baseline function for extracting text from primary research articles
>   using rules that developers can customize.