# How to get the same result as copy and pasting pdf to text using python?

Tags: python, pdf, text, copy-paste

When I copy and paste a pdf document into a text file using ctrl+a, ctrl+c, ctrl+v I get a result like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3XZ7.png):

but when I use pdfminer with the code below i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81D1p.png):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

*....*

def scrub(self):
    text = self.convert(self.inFile)
    with open(self.WBOutputFile, "w") as WBOut:
        WBOut.write(text)

#code from Tim Arnold at https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167
def convert(self, fname):
    pagenums = set()

    output = StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    infile = file(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close
    return text

*....*
```

The code takes several seconds longer than doing it manually but I want to automate this pdf to text process because I have a lot of documents. Is there a way to get similar result (in terms of speed and formatting) similarly to copy and paste? I am using chrome as my pdf viewer, sublime text as my text editor, and windows 8 as my OS.

I am using pdf from http:// www. supremecourt.gov/oral_arguments/argument_transcripts/14-8349_n648 .pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract text from a PDF file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583535/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-in-python)

Comment: I tried using pyPdf before but I wasn't able to get simple formatting from it either. My question is more specific to whether or not python can use similar method as ctrl-a-c-v to copy text from pdf.

Comment: I think Chrome is doing something clever to allow you to select and copy sections of text. A PDF is really formatted for printing, and the semantic structure of the document is no longer important. You might have to do a lot of work to reconstitute lines, paragraphs, etc.

Comment: @kkawabbat - great question and hard to understand why it's so difficult to find a good solution - did you ever find anything?

Comment: Sadly no, I just used pdfminer.

Answer (score 2):

try setting the char_margin in the laparams to 50.

i.e.

```
laparams=LAParams()
laparams.char_margin = float(50)
converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)
```